# Responsive Design - Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, fullpage.js

I am in the process of developing a responsive website which I am. For some reason when I resize the browser, responsiveness work good, however when I load the site on a mobile, the responsiveness is not working correctly.

This is the website:

http://rcb.com.mt/wordpresstesting/WebsiteTest/

I also run a test on an online responsive tester website and responsiveness is working too:
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frcb.com.mt%2Fwordpresstesting%2FWebsiteTest%2F

I am using this plugin in my website: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js - Could it be something to do with a setting or a callback function in the script ?

Can anyone have a look for me and maybe discover why the responsiveness isn't functioning correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "the responsiveness is not working correctly."

Comment: Hi there. Questions of the form 'please look at my external link' are not appropriate for Stack Overflow. They are too time-sensitive, since the question becomes useless once you fix it, or if the site disappears. It is better to create a code example of your problem in your question, so that it remains useful for readers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the viewport tag in the `<head>` is missing, add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```